# Fixed-point free representation of a Lie group G, with non-trivial fixed points for proper subgroup

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Assume we have a compact Lie group $G$ and a closed proper subgroup $H$. Is there an elementary way to see that there is a finite dimensional representation $V$ of $G$ with only trivial fixed points $V^G=\{0\}$, but such that $V^H\neq \{0\}$?

Comment: Is there a non-elementary way?

Comment: I guess I would be happy with any explanation, I was just hoping there would be an elementary one

Comment: Why do you believe it is true?